# Error submitting form on Discord server using my discord bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So now my data is being saved into database but the form on discord is not submiting it shows something went wrong on form but the form doesnt close but still i get the success message on my discord  channel

here is the code link
[code link](https://srcshare.io/65f515261484a59ebf6dd532)

screen shot link
[screen shot link](https://ibb.co/CwPKj1j)

see behind form it says You have been successfully registered!

I tried to see the database if it actually saves the data inside the DB and yes it does but my form is not submiting it just says something wrong but shows registration successful